# How to add routes to my navigation in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, routes, navigation, dropdown, router

I have a navigation within a drawer, that renders titles from an array, and now I want to be able to click and be redirected to another page, but I cant mangage to solve this problem, Can you help me figure out how to do this the right way? I am using Vue.

**This is my navbar:**

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <v-app-bar prominent flat app style="background-color: white;">
      <div class="wrap row">
        <div class="hamburger col-lg-2">
          <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        </div>

        <div class="headerImg col-lg-8">
          <router-link to="/">
            <img class="image" :src="require('../img/eagle.jpg')" />
          </router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer" app temporary class="navigation">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="SidebarHeader text-center">
          <router-link to="/">
            <div class="img"></div>
          </router-link>
        </div>



        <!-- PARENT -->

        <ul class="idb-nav list-unstyled m-15 p-0">
          <div v-for="(menu, index) in navigation.subnav" :key="index">
            <li class="nav-item" v-if="navigation.route && navigation.route.length">
              <a
                :class="[ 'nav-link', { 'active': menu.active } ]"
                href="javascript:void(0);"
                @click="toggleMenu(index)"
              >
                <i
                  v-if="item.subnav"
                  class="fas"
                  :class="{'fa-chevron-down' :!item.open, 'fa-chevron-up' :item.open}"
                ></i>
                <span class="menu-title">{{navigation.title}}</span>
              </a>

              <!-- CHILDREN -->

              <ul class="list-unstyled sub-menu">
                <router-link
                  tag="li"
                  v-for="(navigation, key) in navigation.subnav"
                  :key="key"
                  :to="subnav.route"
                >
                  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub-menu-nav-link">
                    <span>{{subnav.title}}</span>
                  </a>
                </router-link>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <Dropdown v-if="item.subnav" :list="item" />
          </div>
        </ul>


      </div>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import Dropdown from "./Dropdown";

export default {
  computed: {
    navigation() {
      return this.$store.getters.navigation;
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      drawer: false
    };
  },
  components: {
    Dropdown
  }
};
</script>
```

**And here is my index.js file:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'



Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {

    navigation: [
      {
        title: "Historia",
        route: './views/Historia'
      },
      {
        title: "Elgitarrer",
        open: false,
        subnav: [
          {
            title: "Solid guitars",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Solid'
          },
          {
            title: "Semi solid guitars",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Semisolid'
          },
          {
            title: "Archtop guitars",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Archtop'
          },
          {
            title: "Thin archtop guitars",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Thinarchtop'
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Elbasar",
        open: false,
        subnav: [
          {
            title: "Kontrabas",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Kontrabas'
          },
          {
            title: "Bas",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Bas'
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Akustiskt",
        open: false,
        subnav: [
          {
            title: "Nylonsträngade",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Nylon'
          },
          {
            title: "Stålsträngade",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Steel'
          },
          {
            title: "Akustisk bas",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Akustiskbas'
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Övrigt",
        open: false,
        subnav: [
          {
            title: "Banjo/Mandolin",
            open: false,
            route: './views/BanjoMandolin'
          },
          {
            title: "Ukulele",
            open: false,
            route: './views/Ukulele'
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "Kontakt",
        open: false,
        route: './views/Kontakt'
      },
    ],

  },
  getters: {
    navigation: state => {
      return state.navigation;
    }
  }
})
```

Please help me!

/ Lisa

Comment: it seems like you are missing the vue-router routes definition ? you basically defined your routes in vuex, but you'll need to define the routes in your router. You can however re-use your definition there. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html 
Did you setup your project with the vue-cli? Then you probably already have the files in place

Comment: I recommend The Net Ninja's excellent Vue tutorial on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gQcYgjhBoeQH7wiAyZNrYa), lesson 39 onwards deals with routing.  You need a [VueRouter](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript) object to instantiate a set of routes which you will use in your Vue app.

Comment: Hey Lisa,  please check out this free video for using vue router. https://vueschool.io/courses/vue-router-for-everyone (~1 hour)

Comment: Ok, but how can I put up the routes in my router? I am new to vue and I have followed many tutorials and examples, but I also think that I have made it harder for me by mixing everything. haha.

Answer (score 0):

You are using vuex for routing, instead use vue-router plugin. On vue documentation there's a chapter about routing your app https://router.vuejs.org/guide/#javascript

Comment: Thanks, but do I have to uninstall vuex in order to use the vue-router plugin? Or do I just leave it as it is?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but do I have to uninstall vuex in order to use the vue-router plugin? Or do I just leave it as it is?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies in your `router-link` loop:

```
<router-link
  tag="li"
  v-for="(navigation, key) in navigation.subnav"
  :key="key"
  :to="subnav.route"
>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub-menu-nav-link">
    <span>{{subnav.title}}</span>
  </a>
</router-link>
```

You have to access each iteration using the variable that represents it (which is `navigation` in your case). So instead, it should be like this:

```
<router-link
  tag="li"
  v-for="(navigation, key) in navigation.subnav"
  :key="key"
  :to="navigation.route"
>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="sub-menu-nav-link">
    <span>{{navigation.title}}</span>
  </a>
</router-link>
```

With that being said, the string represented in the `route` attribute (e.g `'./views/Archtop'`) is not a valid route path in terms of vue-router, it looks like a reference to the component itself which should be declared in the corresponding route object in the vue-router instance.

For more information about vue-router see the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/).